# Determine which values are missing from an Oracle database column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of values and I want to query which values in that list DO NOT appear in a particular column in an Oracle database (not sure which version).

So for example if my list of values is `A,B,C` and I have a table as below :

```
--------
|COLUMN|
--------
|     C|
|     A|
--------
```

The result I would expect would be `B`.

So far my approach has been a SQL query similar to the below :

```
SELECT <<List of values SQL, not sure what goes here>>
EXCEPT
SELECT column FROM table
```

However I do not know what the SQL for the first statement looks like.
So far I came up with :

```
SELECT "A","B","C" FROM dual
```

But this doesn't have the desired effect as it creates 3 columns

Another point to mention is that in the actual problem there are around 100 entries in the list to search, not the three in the toy example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
WITH static_list AS (
  SELECT 'A' AS v FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS v FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' AS v FROM dual
)
SELECT v FROM static_list 
 MINUS (SELECT column 
          FROM table);
```

Comment: One thing is that the actual list of values is a lot larger, around 112 values so you end up with a large With statement. Will try this solution

Comment: You can create a separate table and insert your values in there. Then you replace `static_list` with this new table.

Comment: I guess you could do this with a temporary table, I am not in a situation where I can easily create new permanent tables. I ended up using the With statement with a lot of selects so accepting

Answer (score 0):

Dirk's solution works fine. However, Regular Expressions can also be used for achieving this goal for Oracle 10g and above:

```
SELECT trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level)) str
FROM (SELECT 'A,B,C,D' str from dual)
CONNECT BY instr(str, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
Minus
Select column from table
```